how to solve circular import error when importing torchvision?
How to solve circular import error in import torchvision?
Here is the log output of the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/443/plugins/python/helpers-pro/pydevd_asyncio/pydevd_asyncio_utils.py", line 117, in _exec_async_code
    result = func()
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/443/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/envs/my-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from torchvision import _meta_registrations, datasets, io, models, ops, transforms, utils
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/443/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/envs/my-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/_meta_registrations.py", line 26, in <module>
    def meta_roi_align(input, rois, spatial_scale, pooled_height, pooled_width, sampling_ratio, aligned):
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/envs/my-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/_meta_registrations.py", line 18, in wrapper
    if torchvision.extension._has_ops():
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'torchvision' has no attribute 'extension' (most likely due to a circular import)


This question is similar to: ImportError: cannot import name '...' from partially initialized module '...' (most likely due to a circular import). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
